# Finding which points that are valid for our point hitting (4,0) when leaving the orbit in a straight line.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

So basically the problem is that we have a satellite that is orbiting around this equation:

$3x^2-2xy+7y^2 - 20 = 0$

And it looks like this in graph form:
[the orbit of the so said planet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wTN4.png)

At what points can the satellite that is leaving the orbit in a straight line to pass the point $(4,0)$ on the way out into space?
I think I remember something with setting up all the equations that must apply to the $x$ value at this point and then solving that equation system. But I can't remember how to do so.

TL;DR Finding at which point our satellite will need to be to hit $(4,0)$.

Sorry for my bad English; it's my third language so I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem needs to be defined a bit more precisely.  When you say "leaving orbit", that can be done in many ways.  If you mean "in a straight line" (impractical but possible with enough fuel) then you are looking for tangent lines.  Otherwise I'm not sure what the goal is.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Oh my bad. Yeah like you said. At what point(s) would x and y have to be to hit (4,0) when leaving the orbit in a straight line. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Consider the problem geometrically, to start.  You are looking to draw two tangent lines, each that passes through $(4,0)$, and each of which touches exactly one point on the ellipse.  Pertinent questions:  [1] What is the slope of the line from $(4,0)$ to $(x,y)$? [2] What is the derivative of the ellipse at $(x,y)$?  You need to find the two distinct points on the ellipse where the answers to questions [1] and [2] are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=m(x-4)$$
is the equation of a generic line passing through $(4,0)$

If we want the intersection points between the line and the ellipse, we must solve the system
$$\begin{cases}
3 x^2-2 x y+7 y^2-20=0\\
y=mx-4m\\
\end{cases}$$
substitute the second equation into the first to get
$$3x^2-2x(mx-4m)+7(mx-4m)^2-20=0$$
expand and collect $x$
$$\left(7 m^2-2 m+3\right) x^2+\left(8 m-56 m^2\right) x+112 m^2-20=0\tag{1}$$
The line is tangent to the ellipse if this equation has only one root, that means that its discriminant must be zero.
$$D=\left(8 m-56 m^2\right)^2-4\left(7 m^2-2 m+3\right)(112 m^2-20)=0$$
$$D=-80 \left(9 m^2+2 m-3\right)=0\to m=\frac{1}{9} \left(-1\pm 2 \sqrt{7}\right)$$
To find the actual points of tangency, substitute the values of $m$ into $(1)$

$$m=\frac{1}{9} \left(-1+ 2 \sqrt{7}\right)\to x=\frac{1}{6} \left(10-\sqrt{7}\right);\;y=\frac{1}{9} \left(-1+ 2 \sqrt{7}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6} \left(10-\sqrt{7}\right)-4\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$$

$$m=\frac{1}{9} \left(-1- 2 \sqrt{7}\right)\to x=\frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{7}+10\right);\;y=\frac{1}{9} \left(-1- 2 \sqrt{7}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6} \left(10+\sqrt{7}\right)-4\right)=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$$
The possible points are
$$P_1\left(\frac{1}{6} \left(10-\sqrt{7}\right);\;-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right);\;P_2\left(\frac{1}{6} \left(10+\sqrt{7}\right);\;\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)$$